# Copy files into a folder until it reaches a certain size

Tags: go

I have a folder named "myfolder" that has some txt and jpeg files and and a folder named "test".
I want to copy files inside myfolder to test until it reaches a certain size, for example 10MB, then stop to copy.

This is my code that does not work:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strconv"
)

var (
    MyFolderPath = "/home/jim/myfolder"
    files        []string
)

func copy(source []string, destination string) {

    for a, b := range source {
        input, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(b)
        ioutil.WriteFile(destination+strconv.Itoa(a), input, 0777)
    }

}

func CopyFile(path string) {
    var size int64
    done := errors.New("size reached")
    err := filepath.Walk(path, func(_ string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        copy(files[1:], fmt.Sprintf("%v/test/%v", MyFolderPath, "file"))
        size += info.Size()

        if size > 10000 {
            return done
        }

        return err

    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}

func CollectFiles() {
    err := filepath.Walk(MyFolderPath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        files = append(files, path)
        return nil

    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    CollectFiles()
    CopyFile(fmt.Sprintf("%v/test", MyFolderPath))
}
```

What I do wrong and how can I do in right way?

Comment: At first glance there are several things I would do differently:  

  - first make sure you check for errors, you shouldn't discard errors from ioutil in copy()
  
  - the correct way to handle errors in a func is to return it, not to print it in the func, this way you can stop execution in main when you have an error (after printing it)
  
  - avoid globals, you could return a new []string and return it in your CollectFiles() ([]string, error)

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it doesn't work." What doesn't work? What behavior do you observe? What do you expect instead?

Comment: Obviously I expect that copy until the folder reaches 10000 bytes. But copy more than 10000 bytes

Comment: That's not at all obvious from your description. "It doesn't work" can mean anything, including it copies nothing, or it returns an error, or it crashes or doesn't compilie.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
    copy(files[1:], fmt.Sprintf("%v/test/%v", MyFolderPath, "file"))
```

Every time you find a file match, you tell it to (re)-copy *every* file in your `files` slice, except the first one.

You probably want to copy a single file there.

Although your code is difficult to reason through--I'm not sure why `files` exists at all, nor why you're walking your directory structure twice. So your goals aren't really clear, so it's hard to be more specific.

Also note: You should not use `copy` as the name of a function, as that is a [built-in](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy), so makes your code very confusing to read.

Answer (score -4):

You have multiple places where you're wrong. Perhaps check this code and compare:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

var (
    MyFolderPath   = "/tmp"
    DestPath       = "/tmp/dest"
    CumulativeSize int64 = 0 // in bytes
    ErrDone = errors.New("done")
)

const UpperLimit = 1024 * // 1 Kilobyte
    1024 * // 1 Megabyte
    10 // 10 Megabytes

func main() {
    err := filepath.Walk(MyFolderPath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("problem with file (%s): %v", path, err)
            return nil
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return filepath.SkipDir // skip it, walk will enter it too
        }
        CumulativeSize += info.Size()

        if CumulativeSize >= UpperLimit {
            return ErrDone
        }

        // copy file here

        return nil
    })

    if err == ErrDone {
        fmt.Println("finished successfully")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is correct or not, but without commentary explaining what you corrected, it's an incomplete answer, at best.